# Prevent parent directories from being tarred

Tags: shell, tar

Basically I just want to tar all the files in a directory, but not get all the parent directories in the archive.

I've tried -C, but I guess I'm not using it right.

```
tar -cjf archive.tar.bz2 -C /var/some/log/path ./*
```

This results in tar trying to add all the files in the CWD. Using the full path as last argument doesn't prevent the dirs from being added.

Seems simple enough, but can't figure it out. Somehow tar does not tar ./* as being relative to -C, although it should change to that dir.

Help appreciated.

Comment: It's the shell that expands  `./*` into a list of file names. `tar` only sees this list of file names.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The parent directory (`/var/some/log`) is included, since `/var/some/log/path/..` is included when you do `./*`. Try just doing

```
tar -cjf archive.tar.bz2 -C /var/some/log/path .
```

Test run:

```
$ find tmp/some_files
tmp/some_files
tmp/some_files/dir1
tmp/some_files/dir1/dir1file
tmp/some_files/hello
tmp/some_files/world
tmp/some_files/dir2
tmp/some_files/dir2/dir2file
$ tar -cvjf archive.tar.bz2 -C tmp/some_files/ .
./
./dir1/
./dir1/dir1file
./hello
./world
./dir2/
./dir2/dir2file
$ cd tmp/unpacked
/tmp/unpacked$ mv /home/aioobe/archive.tar.bz2 .
/tmp/unpacked$ tar -xvjf archive.tar.bz2 
./
./dir1/
./dir1/dir1file
./hello
./world
./dir2/
./dir2/dir2file
/tmp/unpacked$ ls
archive.tar.bz2  dir1  dir2  hello  world
/tmp/unpacked$
```

Comment: That's somewhat better, but now it ads "." as a parent directory in the tar. I want only the files.

Comment: No, the "./" prefix is just notation. It contains the files in the "root" of the archive.

Comment: To avoid . displayed in the root directory (for example in the file-roller) you could just
tar -cjf archive.tar.bz2 -C /var/some/log/ path/
Then the latest element "path" is displayed then in the root directory. The explanation: -C means "change to this directory" and last argument "tar that directory".

Comment: @aioobe The "./" prefix is not necessarily notation.  On my machine I get a folder named "." as the parent in the above example, whereas if I change directories and then tar, the "./" goes away and I'm left with all the files in the root of the archive.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much easier way to do this:

1. `cd` down to the directory you wish to be top level, i.e...

   `cd /var/lib/mysql`
2. Remove parent directories from your tar command

   `/var/lib/mysql/DATABASE_NAME` becomes just `DATABASE_NAME`

More details can be found in [this blog writeup](http://frankkoehl.com/2011/04/remove-parent-directories-from-tar-archives).